# jest spyOn navigator.mediaDevices

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, jestjs, spy

I am writing a small library at the moment to help with connecting to media devices, it would be nice if I could unit test the library, I have a function in my typescript library that looks like this,

```
static connectAudioDevice(device?: InputDeviceInfo) : Promise<MediaStream> {
    return new Promise<MediaStream>((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
            .then(stream => {
                resolve(stream);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                resolve(error);
            })
    })
}
```

I want to use `jest.spyOn` to mock the `getUserMedia` is this possible? Something like,

```
import devices from '@/assets/lib/devices.ts';

test('Resolves with valid audio mediaStream', () => {

    const audioStream = {};
    let promise = devices.connectAudioDevice();

    jest.spyOn(window.navigator.mediaDevices, 'getUserMedia', promise);

})
```

But I am getting the error:

> Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

Can anyone offer me some help?

Answer (score 6):

The `navigator.mediaDevices` is not implemented by JSDOM. So `window.navigator.mediaDevices` is `undefined`, that's why you got the error. Take a look at [Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom).

The solution is:

`device.ts`:

```js
export default class Devices {
  public static connectAudioDevice(device?: InputDeviceInfo): Promise<MediaStream> {
    return new Promise<MediaStream>((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          resolve(stream);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          resolve(error);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

`device.test.ts`:

```js
import devices from './deivce';

describe('65112057', () => {
  test('Resolves with valid audio mediaStream', async () => {
    const mockMediaDevices = {
      getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data' as any),
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
      writable: true,
      value: mockMediaDevices,
    });
    const actual = await devices.connectAudioDevice();
    expect(actual).toBe('fake data');
    expect(mockMediaDevices.getUserMedia).toBeCalledWith({ audio: true });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/65112057/device.test.ts
  65112057
    ✓ Resolves with valid audio mediaStream (7ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |       80 |      100 |       75 |       80 |                   |
 deivce.ts |       80 |      100 |       75 |       80 |                10 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.994s, estimated 13s
```

Comment: can you help me with this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71736624/jest-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getvideotra