# How to mock navigator mediaDevices for Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, navigator

I have a test that needs to use `navigator.mediaDevices` but I cannot get any mocks to work correctly.

I am using `create-react-app`.

Here is my test:

```
import getConnectedDevices from "./getConnectedDevices";

describe("getConnectedDevices", () => {
  it("Should work", () => {
    console.log(navigator);              // Navigator {}
    console.log(navigator.mediaDevices); // undefined
  });
});
```

I have tried adding a mock as it states [here in the jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)

```js
// tests/navigator.mock
Object.defineProperty(window, "navigator", {
  writable: true,
  value: {
    mediaDevices: {
      enumerateDevices: jest.fn(),
    },
  },
});
```

```
import "../../tests/navigator.mock"; // <- Mock added

import getConnectedDevices from "./getConnectedDevices";

describe("getConnectedDevices", () => {
  it("Should work", () => {
    console.log(navigator);              // Navigator {}
    console.log(navigator.mediaDevices); // undefined
  });
});
```

I have also tried [Initializing the test environment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment) according to the create-react-app docs.

```
// src/setupTests.ts

// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

const navigatorMock = {
  mediaDevices: {
    enumerateDevices: jest.fn(),
  },
};

global.navigator = navigatorMock;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that because there already is a `navigator` object, it's not possible to re-assign it.

Thanks to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957674/4638376), you mock the object within the `navigator` and assign it to the existing navigator object.

```js
// src/setupTests.ts

const mediaDevicesMock = {
  enumerateDevices: jest.fn(),
};

global.navigator.mediaDevices = mediaDevicesMock; // here
```

Note: This will throw a TSC error `Cannot assign to 'mediaDevices' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)`. Still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: You can use `Object.defineProperty()`, and don't forget to add `{ writable: true }` if you're going to overwrite it later in some test.

Answer (score 12):

I did it in typescript:

```
const mockGetUserMedia = jest.fn(async () => {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        resolve()
    })
})

Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
    value: {
        getUserMedia: mockGetUserMedia,
    },
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that with ES6 you can remove the return statement and the curly brackets to simplify your function:
const mockGetUserMedia = jest.fn(
    async () =>
      new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        resolve();
      })
  );

Comment: I think this answer needs more clarifying info. Where exactly is this called in comparison to the tests and are there any libraries needed outside of jest?
 I also tried implementing this code and it does not add 'mediaDevices' to the navigator property for me.

Comment: You can simplify to

`const mockGetUserMedia = jest.fn(async () => {});`

or

`jest.fn(Promise.resolve);`

Comment: How to mock `getVideoTracks` I am getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVideoTracks')

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Still getting an error.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. However, [this answer worked perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112057/jest-spyon-navigator-mediadevices)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const mediaDevicesMock = jest.fn(async () => {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    resolve();
}); 
});

beforeEach(() => {
 Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'mediaDevices', {
  value: {
    enumerateDevices: mediaDevicesMock,
  },
});
})
```