# Undefined error when mocking globals with Jest and Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm new to unit testing with JS so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

I need to mock the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` method for some tests, so have defined the following in `setupTests.js`:

```js
const mockMedia = {
    getUserMedia: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve(
            "stream"
        ))
}
global.navigator.mediaDevices = mockMedia
```

This works as expected when testing in the same file:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true})
    .then((stream => console.log(stream)))
```

But when testing in my component I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` with the same code.

If I don't try and call the mocked function it appears to exist:

```
console.log(navigator.mediaDevices)

    {
      getUserMedia: [Function: mockConstructor] { ... }
    }
```

But calling results in `undefined`

What am I missing here and thanks in advance

Comment: How did you use the `setupTests.js` file?

Comment: I'm using create-react-app so I think it gets loaded automatically. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of CRA having `resetMocks` default to `true`.

It is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626653/create-react-app-doesnt-properly-mock-modules-from-mocks-directory) other question.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935) the proposal to revert that default value in CRA.

Comment: [This SO question has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112057/jest-spyon-navigator-mediadevices)